# creating lettable rxjs "string.split" operator

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs-lettable-operators

I am attempting to do some `string` manipulation in `rjxs`, and while I **can** accomplish it with the built in behaviors on the `string` class and the `array` class in `Javascript`, I'm wanting to use this as an exercise to learn even more about `rxjs` and understand a fluent code-flow better.

To that end, it's imperative to me that I discover a way to do it that can fit in a `fluent` solution, instead of a series of variable assignments like I see in most `rxjs` examples.

Essentially, here's the situation; I've got a string of text;

```
const example = `
    key || value
    key || value
    key || value

    value
    value

    value
    key || key[key1] = value | key[key2] = value
    key || value
`;
```

The first thing that I need to do is use `string.split('\n')` to create an array of strings, so that I can through each line and perform further operation.

`example.string.split('\n')` does give the desired results, but trying to send this into `rxjs` begins to get rather mixed yield. With the `pipe` method, I know that I send the results into `rxjs` as an `Observable`, but I'm having a really troubling time grasping how to truly treat it from there without excessive nesting into the `map` operator.

For example, if I do ...

```
of(example.string.split('\n')).pipe(
   map(results => results.toString().split('||')),
   map(results => ... ),
   ...
).subscribe();
```

I **can** start to get a semblance of what I'm looking for, but what I'd really like to do is ...

```
of(example).pipe(
   split('\n'),
   split('||'),
   concatMap(results => ...)
).subscribe();
```

Reading the [documentation on `lettable operators`, seen here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md), it looks like this should be a pretty easy thing to create. In theory, it should look like this in my mind;

```
const split = (separator: string) => <T>(source: Observable<T>) =>
    new Observable(observer => {
        source.subscribe({
            next(x) { observer.next(x.toString().split(separator)); },
            error(err) { observer.error(err); },
            complete() { observer.complete(); }
        })
    });
```

So that should make the whole code obvious enough;

```
of(example).pipe(
    split('\n')
).subscribe(result => console.log(`[n]::${result}`));
```

But this doesn't give me what I really expect. I expected to get an `array` of the lines, but if I output it, I get ...

> [n]::,    key || value,    key || value,    key || value,    ,
>   value,    value,    ,    value,    key || key[key1] = value |
>   key[key2] = value,    key || value,

I'm really unclear what I'm doing wrong, here. Since it's hard to demonstrate `rxjs` in most of the code playgrounds like `plunkr` or `jsfiddle`, at least to my knowledge, I've prepared a playground environment to demonstrate my work on `stackblitz`, if it helps.

You'll find all of the pertinent code in the `playground/index.ts` file. I've done the best I can to abstract away the need to have **any** knowledge of angular, as I've painstakingly earmarked the sections that should be left alone to make it continue showing output on the right side. If you do not know angular, but can help with `rxjs`, you should be able to work without ever disturbing that setup.

### [STACKBLITZ PLAYGROUND](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-lettable-experiments-3hjthq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine, just the es6 template string  ${} flattened your array into a string. If you console.dir or log the result, you will see a correct array retrieved.

Comment: But if I call, say, a `map` after the `split`, it's like it isn't really a `string[]`.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-lettable-experiments-ovl17r?file=playground/index.ts
Please check the console for your forked version